# SAS DM - Getting Rid of the Results Tab

Tags: configuration, sas, display-manager

I'm looking for a way to get rid of the Results Tab, keeping only the Explorer Tab which can itself display the results. However, WSAVE ALL doesn't "remember" that configuration detail, and even when I manually close it, it keeps showing up again every time I run a procedure which generates results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what seems to be a durable solution. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Activate the Explorer pane. Go to Options > Tools > Explorer... and under the General tab, make sure Results is checked (by default, it is not).
2. In your autoexec.sas file, inclure the following line:

   dm "odsresults; cancel";
3. Restart SAS

Et voilà!

The Results pane is now gone, and the results will appear as usual in a Results Viewer window with the items listed directly in the Explorer Window (turn on the tree view to easily access both your libraries and the output items. Use WSAVE ALL in the commands window for SAS to remember that configuration).

Note 1: Under Windows, the autoexec.sas file can be saved in the %userprofile% directory.

Note 2: To get rid of the obsolete Output window when using only ODS-style outputs, add this line to autoexec.sas:

```
dm "Output; winclose";
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for a while for the WSAVE ALL command, which I cannot get to work. I read the second part of your question. Results can be disabled by altering the Output Delivery System (ODS) settings in SAS. ODS is too broad to cover in full here, but the two statements to run are:

```
ods results off; /* Stops results being generated */
ods listing; /* Turns on the old-style listing so you can see the output */

/* print a sample */
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
```

To automate this for your session, you can add these statements to your `autoexec.sas` file, or there may be options you can add to the `sasv9.cfg` files, find the locations for these by running:

```
%put %sysfunc(getoption(config));
```

At any point you can reverse the behaviour by running:

```
ods results;
ods listing off;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... The thing is, I don't want to deactivate ods output. I just want to get rid of the results pane (tab). If you activate the explorer pane, and go to Tools > Options > Explorer > General and check "Results", you get to see the results items directly in the Explorer pane, making the Results pane redundant. So I'm just looking for a way to get rid of it, without turning off ods results.

Comment: If you're really keen to get rid of it, look into editing the registry using the REGISTRY Procedure. Take a backup of the registry first and take care! http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000764127.htm

Comment: Yes that's where I'm at... Using the Registry Editor is easier than with the procedure (Solutions > Accessories > Registry Editor. So far no success but will post the solution if I find one! :)